# Atom edit multiple highlight select

Tags: atom-editor

Using [multiple-highlight-select](https://atom.io/packages/multi-highlight-selected) I can select a single word and all instances will be highlighted. Is there a way to select a word and edit all instances?

Comment: By "instances", do you mean word instances or variable instances?  I'm trying to figure out if my question is a duplicate before I ask.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of boring find-and-replace, you can edit all instances with *multi-cursor*.

- Select a word (by double-clicking on it or press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to select a word under the cursor).
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to select all occurrences and to create *multi-cursor*.
- Type/delete chars — this will affect all occurrences!
- Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to leave multi-cursor mode.

This works in Atom 1.18.0. On Windows you should use <kbd>win</kbd> instead of <kbd>CMD</kbd> button.

Comment: Seems like now it's not `CTRL` + `CMD` + `g`, but `ALT` + `F3`. [Manual](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/editing-and-deleting-text/#multiple-cursors-and-selections)

Answer (score 10):

You can select several occurrences of the same word using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> repeatedly, or select all the occurrences by typing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Then just start typing in order to edit all the occurrences at once. (press <kbd>escape</kbd> when you are done to return to normal "single" editing)

---

Otherwise, using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> when you are on a word will open the find and replace panel for this word.

Then use <kbd>tab</kbd> to go into the "replace in current buffer' field, and type your replacement word.

Finally, hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to replace the occurrences one by one, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to replace all.